# Scroll on recycler view and make a text view move with a specific item in the recycler view while text could be longer than the width of a item view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I have a horizontal recycler view and have items in it. Now, I want to add a title, which could be pretty long, above a specific item. When scrolling, I want that text view move along with that item while the text could be pretty long and exceed the item's layout. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use textView with fixed width and apply autosize xml attribute the the text will auto resize according to the length of the text/

```
<TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="200dp"
          app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but won't this push the following items back?